# likelihood of latent state space model

Tags: monte-carlo, likelihood, latent-variable, state-space-models

Im trying to calculate the likelihood function of my latent state space model.

My model has Poisson observations

$p(y_t|\beta_t;x_t) \sim \mathcal{Poiss}(z)$.

where $z$ is the rate of the poisson process,  $z = exp(\beta_t \cdot x_t)$ and $x_t$ are observed covariates on which the rate may depend

and evolves as a linear dynamical system.

$p(\beta_t|\beta_{t-1}) \sim \mathcal{N}(A\cdot \beta,Q)$

I'm trying to compare this model with a simpler model with fixed parameters (i.e. just a simple poisson regression). It is my understanding that to compare these models I need to calculate $p(y|\theta)$ in both cases but am unsure how to calculate this for the latent variable model.

In order to fit the latent model I've used the EM algorithm outlined here, making a laplace approximation to adjust for the nonlinear observation process: http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/course04/tr-96-2.pdf.

The authors provide a closed form expression of the joint likelihood $p(x,y)$ of data and latent variables but I'm unsure how to calculate the likelihood.

My current thinking is that I need to integrate out the latent variables $x$; i.e.

$p(y|\theta) = \int p(x,y|\theta)  \ dx $

The only way I can think of doing this, since there is no closed form equation for the $p(x|y)$ is some kind of (markov chain) monte carlo approach. Is this correct or am I just way off?

Comment: How does $z_t$ relate to $\beta_t$ and $x_t$?

Comment: Clarified, z is the rate of the poisson process: =(⋅)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not exact, the laplace approximation can be used to estimate the marginal likelihood.

$log \ p(Y|\theta)  \approx log \ p(Y|\hat{\beta_{\theta}},\theta) + log \ p(\hat{\beta_{\theta}}|\theta)  - \frac{1}{2} \cdot log  \ | -H_{\theta} | + K$

where K is constant independent of $\theta$, $\hat{\beta_{\theta}}$ is the MAP estimate of $\beta$ condition on $\theta$.

see pp117 of http://www.columbia.edu/~kr2248/publication/Paninski10.pdf for details.

In general, it does seem monte carlo methods are required to calculate the exact marginal likelihood.